# Visual Studio Team Services: Task Colour Blue?

Tags: azure-devops

Why is the colour of tasks inside Visual Studio Team Services suddenly the same blue as the Backlog items? Before is was yellow and therefore easy to distinguish.

It is just everywhere where it was yellow before, now blue:
[image: Card]
This affects not only this window but it is also in the "tree".
[image: Tree]

The process shows it still yellow (I use the scrum template with small customisation):
[image]

It should be yellow according to the process:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot if possible. ?

Comment: @Harshil Lodhi See above. This affects not only this window but it is also in the "tree".

Comment: I don't have this issue, the color is still yellow. Do other team projects have the same issue? How about new team project?

Comment: Saw it in all my projects.

Comment: I did not yet create a new team project. However I saw that the process itself still shows yellow (I use scrum with small customisation).

Comment: VSTS is updating, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTS is updating, the updated VSTS could custom the color for work item of Inherited processes:

1. Go to Process admin page
2. Select an Inherited Processes
3. Select Task
4. Click … > Edit and change color

[image]

Comment: According to your instructions I checked the colour. Honestly I did not know that it can be customised. Thanks for this hint. However see my updated post. It looks actually yellow in that window.

Comment: @Matthias Try to change to other color and check the result.

Comment: The colour was actually yellow as I showed you in my screenshot. However I changed the colour to some lighter yellow and now it works!

Comment: That is a bit counter-intuitive that the dialogue shows not the appropriate colour. Very confusing! Also that the default changes. Not the best migration scripts I guess!

Answer (score 2):

We also seeing this on our VSTS.

I suspect this is to do with the change to icons instead of coloured bar, as described here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/articles/news/2017/jun-22-team-services#work-item-type-icons

> Work item type icons We have made a global commitment to make our products fully accessible to our customers. As part of that
>   commitment, we have been working to find and address many
>   accessibility issues—anywhere from keyboard patterns to visual design
>   and layout.
>
> Work item tracking has relied solely on color in many experiences to
>   convey work item type. However, this is problematic for our
>   color-blind or low-vision users who may not be able to distinguish
>   between items due to similarities in color. To increase the
>   scanability of work item types for all our customers, we have
>   introduced icons to our visual language of work item types. You can
>   customize your work item types by choosing from our icon library.
>
> Color bars conveying type on the backlog and queries grids have been
>   replaced with colored icons.

Perhaps the rollout isn't fully complete yet...

See also: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/73306/cards-colour-is-only-blue.html

[image: Work Item Icons]

Comment: I read the same article: I thought the task look still yellow (see yellow icon). I think this is a change they did by accident during the recent work on the new feature. And in my opinion since you confirmed, it is not related to my settings. However it causes issues when I cannot distinguish backlog items and tasks at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with VSTS that was resolved last week. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/73306/cards-colour-is-only-blue.html